# MyLocationNewOverlay not receiving location updates and not beign displayed in view

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am trying to get the MyLocationNewOverlay working in my code but it doesn't seem to be working. I added the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

And the following is my code. I am using a fragment and within it I have the following code written

```
MapView mv=(MapView) getView().findViewById(R.id.f_map);
mv.setVisibility(MapView.VISIBLE);
mv.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
mv.setMultiTouchControls(true);
IMapController mapController = mv.getController();
mapController.setZoom(11);
GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(13.074281, 80.264458);
mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
GpsMyLocationProvider g=new GpsMyLocationProvider(getContext());
g.setLocationUpdateMinTime(1000);
location_overlay=new MyLocationNewOverlay(g,mv);
location_overlay.enableFollowLocation();
location_overlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d("MyTag", String.format("First location fix: %s", location_overlay.getLastFix()));
        }
});   
mv.getOverlays().add(location_overlay);
```

The log is not being printed and that means that location updates are not happening. I also tried outputting the results of `location_overlay.isEnabled()` and `location_overlay.isLocationEnabled()`, both of which return true.

When i try to get the last location by using `location_overlay.getMyLocation()` it returns null.

I also tried switching the source for `GpsMyLocationProvider` by using `g.addLocationSource(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)`.

Still no go. I am not seeing anything in the view nor am I get location updates. Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. I also tried setting min distance for GpsMyLocationProvider`g.setLocationUpdateMinDistance(0);`. Still no result.

Comment: you are outdoors with a suitable, GPS enabled device, right?

Comment: Yes. The appbar shows the GPS searching icon, I assume it is cause of the small update time in GpsMyLocationProvider. I am able to see it in google maps. 
Also when I implement Location Listener in an activity, I am getting updates.